# Linq - group and get list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `L_CabecDocumento` and each one of them has a `L_CabecJob`.
I want to get all unique `L_CabecJob` from each and every `L_CabecDocumento` (i have a `Where` condition).

The problem is that i can't cast it to a `List<L_CabecJob>()`
What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks

```
var lista = (from d in appADO.L_CabecDocumento
               where d.L_TipoEntidadeId == 2  && d.Entidade == fornecedor
               group d by d.CabecJob into c
               select c.Key ).ToList() ;

return  (List<L_CabecJob>)lista;
```

Comment: You should really use English in your code. You can try the `Cast()` method from Linq.

Comment: When you hover the `var lista` in VS, what do you see?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't cast"? I just tried your code and it compiles fine and executes fine, too. What kind of error do you get? The only thing that could go wrong is that `d.CabecJob` is not of type `L_CabecJob`, so `lista` would not be a  `List<L_CabecJob>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead -

```
return  (List<L_CabecJob>)lista;
```

use -

```
return lista.Cast<L_CabecJob>();
```

next time english variables might help us understand youre code better ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)
I managed to get my code working... the problem was on another line.